# Trying to sort PHP associative array by one key

Tags: php, sorting, associative-array

I am trying to sort this associative array in PHP and none of the examples I have found worked.

The unsorted array is built so:

```
                //push into array
            $displayArray = array_push_assoc($displayArray, 'ContactID', $ContactID);
            $displayArray = array_push_assoc($displayArray, 'ContactFirstName', $ContactFirstName);
            $displayArray = array_push_assoc($displayArray, 'ContactLastName', $ContactLastName);
            $displayArray = array_push_assoc($displayArray, 'Ann_Desc', $CG_Desc);
            $displayArray = array_push_assoc($displayArray, 'DaysAway', $daysAway);
```

All I want to do is sort this array in ascending order by values associated with the  'DaysAway' key

I have tried this:

```
            function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            if ($a['DaysAway'] == $b['DaysAway']) {
                return 0;
            }

            return ($a['DaysAway'] < $b['DaysAway']) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        usort($displayArray, 'cmp');

        print_r($displayArray);
        print "<br>";
```

But all this does is seemingly randomly sorts the last row in the original array

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all those `array_push_assoc`, since there's no function by that name.

Instead just put `$displayArray['ContactID'] = $ContactID;` and so on.

You should call `usort` on the parent array that contains each of these `$displayArray` entries, not the `$displayArray` itself.

Comment: You don't think the OP could have his own function with that name?

Comment: Yes, but it's unnecessary overhead when simple syntax can do the same.

Comment: @Kolink: In all fairness, you asked it to be removed `since there's no function by that name.`, not because `it's unnecessary overhead`..Just being a pain in the you-know-where >:)

Comment: Hi Kolink.  I replaced the array_push_assoc as you suggested. Still cannot sort by "DaysAway" though.  How do I "call usort on the parent array?"

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you're actually putting these `$displayArray`s into one big array, and not just overwriting the same variable repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
$b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
  }
  asort($b);
  foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[] = $a[$key];
  }
  return $c;
}
```

$a would be the array you are sorting, while $subkey would be the field you want to sort by.

Comment: Wouldn't `usort($a,'strcasecmp')` do the same thing?

Comment: My original associative array contains four arrays.  After using the above (and other examples), using print_r, I only see one array after the sort..!?